# Json should show up on html table with button push, but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, json

With push of a button there should be a html that contains info from json, but nothing happens.

When i used console.log to show the whole JSON info, it worked. BUt when added table and and only specific arrays, it does nothing. There are no errors.

```html
<button type="button" id="nappi">paina</button> 

<table id="taulu">
    <tr>
        <th>manufacturer</th>
        <th>model</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>wiki</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
var nappi = document.getElementById("nappi");

nappi.addEventListener("click", function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("./cars.json", function(data){
            var tiedot = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                tiedot += '<tr>';
                tiedot += '<td>'+value.manufacturer+'</td>';
                tiedot += '<td>'+value.model+'</td>';
                tiedot += '<td>'+value.price+'</td>';
                tiedot += '<td>'+value.wiki+'</td>';
                tiedot += '</tr>';
            });
                $('taulu').append(tiedot);
        });
    });
});
```

```
{
    "data": [{
        "manufacturer": "Porsche",
        "model": "911",
        "price": 135000,
        "quality": [{
            "name": "overall",
            "rating": 3
        }, {
            "name": "mechanical",
            "rating": 4
        }, {
            "name": "powertrain",
            "rating": 2
        }, {
            "name": "body",
            "rating": 4
        }, {
            "name": "interior",
            "rating": 3
        }, {
            "name": "accessories",
            "rating": 2
        }],
        "wiki": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_997"
    }]
}
```

Comment: `$('taulu')` != `$('#taulu')`. Also, makes no sense to have a document-ready callback inside an event callback that itself depends on the DOM being ready.

Comment: Try appending to the body of the table `$('#taulu tbody').append(tiedot);`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `#` before the ID. $(' > **#** < taulu ') `$('#taulu')`